# How to simulate browser back button press using Jasmine Specs?

Tags: browser, jasmine, back-button

I'm using jasmine specs to test our html code(uses Backbone and Require). How to write code to simulate back press functionality using jasmine? Can someone help me?

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but why use sledgehammer for kill mosquito?

Try it:

```
history.go(-1);
```

or:

```
history.back();
```

Or you need capture clicks?

Comment: its not working for me.. as we run specrunner.html if i give history.back its not going to back page